# Doble impresion despues de un return booleano

Tags: c++

El código que estoy elaborando consiste en enviar unos valores a una clase y que esta decida si la fecha ingresada esta correcta o incorrecta.

Estoy teniendo un pequeño problema a la hora de ingresar la siguiente fecha (31/4/2021), el programa me imprime lo siguiente:

> FECHA NO VALIDA...
>
> EL MES DE ABRIL NO PUEDE TENER MAS DE 30 DIAS
>
> FECHA NO VALIDA...
>
> EL MES DE ABRIL NO PUEDE TENER MAS DE 30 DIAS

No entiendo por qué realiza una doble impresión ya que la función que imprime este mensaje no se encuentra en algún bucle.

Éste es mi código:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

class Fecha
{
private:
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
public: 
    Fecha(); 
    void setdia(int  x);
    void setmes(int x);
    void setano(int x);
    void setall(int x, int y, int z);
    int getdia();
    int getmes();
    int getano();
    bool anoBi ();
    bool cantdia();
    bool cantmes();
    bool cantano();
    bool cant_check();
    bool fecha_check();
    void menu();
    void asignacion(int x, int y, int z);
    void ProgPrinc(int x, int y, int z);
    void impresion();
};
Fecha::Fecha(){}
void Fecha::setdia(int  x)
{
    dia=x;
}
void Fecha::setmes(int x)
{
    mes=x;
}
void Fecha::setano(int x)
{
    ano=x;    
}
int Fecha::getdia()
{
    return dia;
}
int Fecha::getmes()
{
    return mes;    
}
int Fecha::getano()
{
    return ano;    
}
bool Fecha::anoBi ()
{
    if((ano%4==0 && ano%100!=0) || ano%400==0) return true;    
    else 
    return false;
    
}
bool Fecha::cantdia()
{
    if(getdia()<0 || getdia()>=32) return true;
    else return false;
}
bool Fecha::cantmes()
{
    if(getmes()<0 || getmes()>12) return true;
    else return false;
}
bool Fecha::cantano()
{
    if(getano()<=0) return true;
    else return false;
}

void Fecha::setall(int x, int y, int z)
{
    setdia(x);
    setmes(y);
    setano(z);
}
void Fecha::menu()
{
    cout<<endl<<"*****************************************"<<endl;
    cout<<" \t EJECUTANDO CLASE.FECHA...."<<endl;
    Sleep(500);
}
void Fecha::asignacion(int x, int y, int z)
{ 
 setall(x,y,z);
}
bool Fecha::cant_check()
{
    if(cantdia()|| cantmes()|| cantano())
    {
        cout<<endl<<"---------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        Sleep(500);
        cout<<"FECHA INTRODUCIDA NO VALIDA"<<endl;
        if(cantdia()) cout<<endl<<"CANTIDAD DE DIA MENOR O IGUAL A CERO O MAYOR A 31"<<endl;
        Sleep(500);
        if(cantmes())cout<<"LA CANTIDAD DEL MES ES MENOR O IGUAL A CERO O MAYOR A 12"<<endl;
        Sleep(500);
        if(cantano())cout<<"LA CANTIDAD DEL AÑO ES MENOR O IGUAL A 0"<<endl;
        Sleep(500);
        cout<<"---------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
bool Fecha::fecha_check()
{
    if((!anoBi() && getmes()==2) && getdia()==29)
    {
        
        cout<<"FECHA NO VALIDA"<<endl;
        cout<<"FEBRERO NO PUEDE TENER 29 DIAS CUANDO EL AÑO NO ES BISIESTO UnU...."<<endl;
        return false;
    }
    switch(mes)
    {
        
        case 4:
            if(dia>30)
            {
            cout<<"FECHA NO VALIDA..."<<endl;
            cout<<"EL MES DE ABRIL NO PUEDE TENER MAS DE 30 DIAS"<<endl;
            return false;
            } 
            break;
        case 6:
            if(dia>30)
            {
            cout<<"FECHA NO VALIDA..."<<endl;
            cout<<"EL MES DE JUNIO NO PUEDE TENER MAS DE 30 DIAS"<<endl;
            return false;
            } 
            break;
        case 9:
            if(dia>30)
            {
            cout<<"FECHA NO VALIDA..."<<endl;
            cout<<"EL MES DE SEPTIEMBRE NO PUEDE TENER MAS DE 30 DIAS"<<endl;
            return false;
            
            } 
            break;
        case 11: 
            if(dia>30)
            {
            cout<<"FECHA NO VALIDA..."<<endl;
            cout<<"EL MES DE NOVIEMBRE NO PUEDE TENER MAS DE 30 DIAS"<<endl;
            return false;
            }
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
void Fecha::ProgPrinc(int x, int y, int z)
{
    menu();
    asignacion(x,y,z);
    //ROOT OF EVIL
    cant_check();
    if(cant_check())fecha_check();
    if(cant_check() && fecha_check())impresion();
}
void Fecha::impresion()
{
    cout<<endl<<endl<<"FECHA INTRODUCIDO CORRECTA UwU , LA FECHA QUE INTRODUJO FUE..."<<endl;
    cout<<getdia() <<'/'<<getmes()<<'/'<<getano();
    if(anoBi())cout<<endl<<"EL AÑO ES BISIESTO...   o. O";
}

int main() 
{
    Fecha p;
    p.ProgPrinc(31,4,2021);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: En la función o método `ProgPrinc` llamas dos veces a la función `bool Fecha::fecha_check()` y por consiguiente aparece dos veces el mensaje.

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes en el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
if (cant_check()) {
    fecha_check();
}
if (cant_check() && fecha_check()) {
    impresion();
}
```

Analicemos el comportamiento de esas líneas:

- Cada vez que se llamen a las funciones, el valor que devolverá `cant_check()` será 1 y `fecha_check()` devolverá 0.
- La primera condición se cumplirá, ejecutando por primera vez la llamada a `fecha_check()` (mostrando el primer mensaje).
- En la segunda condición la primera parte de la expresión lógica es cierta, por lo que debe evaluarse la segunda parte para comprobar el resultado final, ejecutándose de nuevo `fecha_check()` (mostrando el segundo mensaje).